# Backward looking back log report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I'm trying to write a backlog report in Crystal Reports XI attached to Fluke Met/Track database (Sybase back-end)
I have it running between a start & end date, then grouped by Month and then Day.
I need it to show all of the units that were in the lab on the days between the start & end dates

```
October     Units
2
            22525
            22526
3    
            22525
            22526
            22527
4
            22526
            22527
            22530
```

The order of the units doesn't matter, just that the units are showing up.
Maybe I'm just having a rough day, but I'm not seeing how this can be accomplished.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by adding a group for your date, opening up the Group Expert, click your Group click Options, then you should see something along the lines of "The section will be printed:" and you can select: **for each day.**.  This should allow grouping for each day.

Comment: I'm already grouping by each day, but it is only showing items that were logged in for that day